# Use weblogic admin console to manage custom configuration files?

Tags: java, configuration, weblogic, configuration-files

Is there any way I create or upload a configuration file to weblogic server. The configuration file will be used by a java application deployed on the weblogic server. But I can use weblogic server admin console to update this configuration file and don't have to have someone go to the server and find this file and update it in an text editor.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do this.

Comment: which type of configuration file? It is not very clear.

Comment: Any type of configuration file. If we can do xml or a simple property file that would be the best. Could this be possible?

Comment: Yes but what type of properties do you want in this file ? Some properties specific to Weblogic or specific to your application ?

Comment: What I want is use weblogic server admin console to manage and update some custom configuration file. What format does not really matter, and for the properties, all string names with values, if I can use array that would be better. Can you give me example or link shows it is possible to use weblogic console to manage the custom configuration file? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, with Weblogic, I know only how to change some Weblogic properties since  config.xml

Comment: Is it possible to have some custom fields added into config.xml and change these somewhere in the console not have to go open the config.xml and make changes in the editor?

Comment: Sorry, I created an answer by error. yes but these are specific properties for weblogic. I don't think that you could find your fortune. Weblogic Admin provides properties for Weblogic, not  properties customized by the user.

Comment: At least you helped me to confirm this is not possible. Thanks. I will close this question. Can you post the last comment as an anwser? So that I can select it as the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You could create a simple form in jsp with a servlet for your need.

Comment: Right, that might works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Deployment Plans](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/deployment/config.html#wp1057831) for your app. They allow you to customise an EAR or WAR's internal settings.

Bear in mind that early versions of WLS 11g had a bug where specifying a deployment plan at the same time as uploading an app didn't work through the console, and you had to upload, then apply the deployment plan in a separate step (or use WLST or a maven plugin to do it)